# What are some good use cases for Ethereum/ERC20 tokens within the context of a robust delivery app?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ether, decentralization, optimization

Say one wants to operate a e-commerce/delivery service app. The app is essentially a 3 sided service- customer app, rider/driver app and vendor app. Think along the lines of FoodPanda, DoorDash, JustEats, etc. The app needs to be relatively robust in terms of customer payment, driver assignment, and vendor stats.

Customer app will list items(pics, description, price), process payment, etc. There will of course be login and account validation. I want to offer multiple payment options- both fiat (I'm guessing 99.99% of customers will opt for fiat) and crypto.

I need to generate possible routes based on status of available riders on the network for each order, and choose the best route to assign in real-time. I think simplistically this can be solved using a Hungarian algorithm, as I don't want to add the complexity of multi orders yet. [Hungarian optimization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) Also delivery area needs to be tied down to say within a 5 km radius of vendor. Rider needs to be able to accept/reject the order.

Both driver and vendor apps will need to show orders completed and offer payout. I would like to offer instant cashout for drivers. Also ID validation etc..

What are some good use cases for Ethereum/ERC20 tokens within the context of modern delivery apps and the functionality of these systems? Links to articles and specific projects are much appreciated!

Comment: think of ERC20 tokens as Pizza Coupons to get free pizza. That's what they are, it is just that these pizza coupons now can be traded everywhere in the world, and probably on NYSE soon. The hungarian algorithm has abolutely no relation to ERC20 token functionality.

Comment: the only good reason for a company to enter the blockchain platforms is to raise cash from liquidity providers/speculators. Otherwise, a centralized approach (running the app on your server and do everything yourself) is much better way to do things.